# Shiromono means a thing or a person?

Tags: meaning

I got stuck while i was reading manga on this phrase :そんな確実性の高い代物でもねぇだろ
I went to check the translated copy and it says it means" he's not the most reliable guy" a second source said" it's just that this ability isn't that reliable"(the context is a character using her special  ability but fails)

Answer (score 3):

「代物{しろもの}」 means a "thing" 99% of the time.

It would be safe to say that that is what the word means in the sentence in question unless the larger context suggested that it referred to a person.

When it refers to a person, it often refers to a prostitute or a pretty young woman according to [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%A3%E7%89%A9-536402#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88).

> ３ 《売{う}り物{もの}になる意{い}から》遊女{ゆうじょ}。また、年{とし}ごろの美{うつく}しい娘{むすめ}。